# DChange fails to change variables for 1D Schrödinger equation

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

I have a PDE (1D Schrödinger equation) as follows:

[image]

Applying the following transformations to the PDE,
[image]

we get the following ODE:

[image]

I am trying to use @Kuba 's `DChange` package in [the link.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44904/how-to-make-a-change-of-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1) But I can't get the results.

```
 pde = I *D[u[x, y, t], t] - 
   1/2 D[u[x, y, t], {x, 2}] - ( Abs[u[x, y, t]]^2 - A)*u[x, y, t] == 0; 

DChange[pde, {u[x, y, t] == U[ξ]*E^(I*θ), ξ == 
       x + y + α*t, θ == α*x + β*y + γ*t}, {x, y, t}, {ξ}, {u[x, y, t]}]
```

Comment: Maple 2021  answers $$ u\! \left(x,t\right)=-\frac{\tanh\! \left(\frac{3 \,\mathrm{I} A t}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{-A}\, x}{2}-\textit{\_}\mathit{C1}\right) \mathrm{\sqrt{A}}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{A}}{2}$$ and  that was verified for $A=1$.

Comment: @RF_1 Try to use `u = U[\[Xi]]*
    E^(I*\[Theta]) /. {\[Xi] -> 
     x + y + \[Alpha]*t, \[Theta] -> \[Alpha]*x + \[Beta]*
       y + \[Gamma]*t};` and `I*D[u, t] - 
   1/2 D[u, {x, 2}] - (Abs[u]^2 - A)*
    u /. {Im[x \[Alpha] + y \[Beta] + t \[Gamma]] -> 
    0, (x \[Alpha] + y \[Beta] + t \[Gamma]) -> 0} // FullSimplify`

Comment: **How to achieve the transformation above using DSolveChangeVariables introduced in Mathematica 13.1?** please make this separate question.

Comment: I have shared a new question

Comment: The new question is here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/270262/1871

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read the [description of `DChange`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/1871) carefully, you'll find `DChange` owns 3 usages:

> Usage:
>
> ```
> DChange[expresion, {transformations}, {oldVars}, {newVars}, {functions}]
>
> DChange[expresion, "Coordinates1"->"Coordinates2", ...]   
>
> DChange[expresion, {functionsSubstitutions}]
> ```
>
> You can also skip `{}` if a list has only one element.

The first 2 are for change of independent variables, the last 1 for dependent variables, but you've mixed up 1st and 3rd. The correct usage should be:

```
DChange[pde, {ξ == x + y + α t, θ == α x + β y + γ t}, {x, t}, {ξ, θ}, u[x, y, t]]

DChange[%, u[ξ, y, θ] == U[ξ] E^(I θ)]

Assuming[{θ ∈ Reals}, Simplify@%]
(* (2 A + α^2 - 2 γ - 2 Abs[U[ξ]]^2) U[ξ] == U''[ξ] *)
```

Not exactly the same as the one in the picture, but I think it's obvious mine is correct, unless you forgot to mention $u(\xi)>0$ in the question.

BTW, given the example is relatively simple, it's not too bad a choice to transform without `DChange`:

```
func[x_, y_, t_] = With[{ξ = x + y + α t, θ = α x + β y + γ t}, U[ξ] E^(I θ)]

Assuming[{{x, y, t, α, β, γ} ∈ Reals}, pde /. u -> func // Simplify] /. x + y + α t -> ξ
```