# How to change variables in expressions with derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following function:

```
K[r_, h_] = -(D[h[r], {r, 2}] + D[h[r], r]/r + D[h[r], r]^3/r)/(2 (1 + D[h[r], r]^2)^(3/2))
```

In order to non-dimensionalize it, I am performing the change of variables $r=R_cr^*$ etc.

I have tried using

```
h := h1*hc
r := r1*Rc
R := R1*Rc
```

(where I am using `h1` in place of $h^*$, etc.) but when refreshing the expression to get K in function of my new variables and constants $h^*$, $h_c$, $r^*$, $R_c$, $R^*$, I get *"r1/Rc is not a valid variable"*.

I am fairly new to Mathematica. How can I solve this?

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9351/change-variables-in-differential-expressions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you get the error "r1/Rc is not a valid variable" is that Mathematica can't take a derivative with respect to an expression, and your definitions make it so that somewhere in your code, you are trying to do something like

```
 D[h[r1/Rc], r1/Rc]
```

which doesn't make sense.

Instead, I think the most straight-forward way to do this is via replacement rules. The original function is

```
k[r_, h_] = -(D[h[r], {r, 2}] + D[h[r], r]/r + D[h[r], r]^3/r)/(2 (1 + D[h[r], r]^2)^(3/2))
```

We define a list of replacement rules as

```
rules = {Derivative[n_][h][r] :> hC Derivative[n][h1][r1] rC^n, r -> r1*rC};
```

The `hC` out front takes care of the dimension of `h`, and we replace `h` by the non-dimensionalized `h1`. We also multiply by `rC^n` in order to correctly take are of the units on the derivative, replacing `r` by `r1` in the process so that the derivatives are now taken with respect to the non-dimensionalized `r1`. Finally, since there are `r`'s that aren't inside `h`'s, we do one last replacement, explicitly replacing `r` with `r1*rC`.

Then we can define the non-dimensionalized function as

```
kND[r1_, h1_] = k[r, h] /. rules;
```

I don't want to include the entire expression here, but let's look at one of the terms explicitly. For instance, in `k[r, h]`, there is the term `D[h[r], r]/r`. Doing

```
D[h[r], r]/r /. rules // FullForm
```

results in

```
Times[hC, Power[r1, -1], Power[rC, -2], Derivative[1][h1][r1]]
```

which is the same as

```
hC*D[h1[r1], r1]/r1/rC^2
```

which is the correct non-dimensionalization of that term.

#### Extra note

notice that I have changed the names of some of your variables:

```
K -> k
Rc -> rC
```

and so on. It is a good idea to use lower-case names for user-defined symbols so as not to interfere with built in Mathematica functions, which *always* start with capital letters. For instance, `K` is actually a built-in MMA symbol, and so using it to define a function can cause problems.