# Errors while trying to do a change of variable

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following differential equation:

$ \tag{1} \Delta^{-s}\frac{d}{dr}(\Delta^{s+1} \frac{d R(r)}{dr})  + (\frac{K^2 - 2 i s (r - M)K}{\Delta} + 4is \omega r - \lambda)R(r) = 0$

where $\Delta \equiv \Delta(r) = (r - rp)(r - rm), K \equiv K(r)$ and $\lambda$, $rp$, $rm$ are constants. I want to make a change of variable given by:

$\tag{2} x = \frac{r - rp}{rp - rm}$

I saw a similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13240/81739) and I first tried to use this method for a simpler ODE. It seemed to run fine. However, while using it for $(1)$ I am getting some terms that I do not know how to make sense of. Specifically my code is as follows:

```
>$Assumptions[s > 0, m > 0, w > 0,  l > 0, a > 0 , M > 0, rp > 0, rm > 0];
>K[r] = (r^2 + a^2) w - ma;
 \[Lambda] = l (l + 1) - s (s + 1) + (a w)^2 - 2 a m w;
>\[CapitalDelta][r] = Simplify[(r - rp) (r - rm)]
>equ = \[CapitalDelta][r]^(-s) D[{(\[CapitalDelta][r]^(s + 1) D[R[r], r])}, r] + ((K[r]^2 - 2 I s(r - M) K[r])/(\[CapitalDelta][r]) + 4 I s w r - \[Lambda]) R

> Simplify[equ /. {\[CapitalDelta] -> (\[CapitalDelta][(# - rp)/(rp - rm)] &), R -> (R[(# - rp)/(rp - rm)] &)} /. r -> ( x (rp - rm)  + rp)]
```

However, once I run this, I get the following output:

```
{(-l (1 + l) + s (1 + s) + 2 a m w - a^2 w^2 + 4 I s w (rp - rm x + rp x) + ((-ma + w (a^2 + (rp - rm x + rp x)^2)) (-ma + 2 I s (M + rm x - rp (1 + x)) + w (a^2 + (rp - rm x + rp x)^2)))/((rm - rp)^2 x (1 + x))) (R[(#1 - rp)/(rp - rm)] &) + (1 + s) (1 + 2 x) R'[x] + x (1 + x) R''[x]}
```

I don't understand what this term `(R[(#1 - rp)/(rp - rm)] &)` is for instance? Shouldn't that have just been `R[x]`? Why does this happen?
In case a screenshot of my code might be helpful, it can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FENb9.jpg)

Comment: Define the functions K and \[CapitalDelta] with Blank `K[r_] = (r^2 + a^2) w - ma ` and write `R[r] `  at the end of equ.

Comment: Since you give no condition for ma, i think you mean m*a ?

Comment: @Akku14, yes it is m*a

Comment: @Akku14, yes it works now. Thank you. However I am still confused about why `Simplify[(r-rp)(r-rm)]` returns `(r-rp)(r-rm)` and not the expanded form

Comment: `I am still confused about why Simplify[(r-rp)(r-rm)] returns (r-rp)(r-rm) and not the expanded form`  because if you do `term = (r - rp) (r - rm);` and then `LeafCount[term]` gives `11` but `LeafCount[Expand[term]]` gives `15`.  So the expanded term is not simpler and so `Simplify` would not do it. But If you want to expand something, there is a different command for it, called `Expand`